# Reading text file of unknown size

Tags: c, arrays, string, file-io, char

I am trying to read in a text file of unknown size into an array of characters.
This is what I have so far.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

    int main()
    {
            FILE *ptr_file;
            char buf[1000];
        char output[];
            ptr_file =fopen("CodeSV.txt","r");
            if (!ptr_file)
                return 1;   

        while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
            strcat(output, buf);
        printf("%s",output);

    fclose(ptr_file);

    printf("%s",output);
        return 0;
}
```

But I do not know how to allocate a size for the output array when I am reading in a file of unknown size.
Also when I put in a size for the output say n=1000, I get segmentation fault.
I am a very inexperienced programmer any guidance is appreciated :)

The textfile itself is technically a .csv file so the contents look like the following : 
"0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1..."

Comment: If you intend to read 1000 characters, you have to allocate an array of length 1001 (because there is also a \0 character at the end of the string).

Comment: Why do you need to read the whole file into memory? What is the ultimate purpose of your program?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `stat()`/`fstat()` to resolve the fact that you don't know the size of the file? And then possibly just `mmap()` the file, or at least use the now-known file size to advice your file reading code?

Comment: @Ashalynd
I was testing for now, but ultimately I want to read the file into a string, and manipulate the string and output that modified string as a new text file.

Comment: @Amir Notes: Since the file is "unknown size", "to read the file into a string" is not a robust plan.  1) file size can exceed memory/`size_t` capacity.  2) rare embedded `'\0'` from the file pose troubles with C strings.  A better approach is to read in a chunk of text at a time and write to the new file - not necessarily holding the entire file in memory at once.

Comment: Do not you stat() or fstat() if you can avoid it.   Reads do not always from from a actual disk file.  It may be a named pipe, or even a network stream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to use `malloc` to allocate an array of some size, and start reading into it, and if you run out of array before you run out of characters (that is, if you don't reach `EOF` before filling up the array), pick a bigger size for the array and use `realloc` to make it bigger.

Here's how the read-and-allocate loop might look.  I've chosen to read input a character at a time using `getchar` (rather than a line at a time using `fgets`).

```
int c;
int nch = 0;
int size = 10;
char *buf = malloc(size);
if(buf == NULL)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
    }

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
    if(nch >= size-1)
        {
        /* time to make it bigger */
        size += 10;
        buf = realloc(buf, size);
        if(buf == NULL)
            {
            fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
            exit(1);
            }
        }

    buf[nch++] = c;
    }

buf[nch++] = '\0';

printf("\"%s\"", buf);
```

Two notes about this code:

1. The numbers 10 for the initial size and the increment are much too small; in real code you'd want to use something considerably bigger.
2. It's easy to forget to ensure that there's room for the trailing '\0'; in this code I've tried to do that with the `-1` in `if(nch >= size-1)`.

Comment: Rather than `int size = 10; ... size += 10;` suggest `size_t size = 10; ... size *= 2;`.  Code could even do a final `realloc()` to right-size the buffer.

Comment: @chux: I usually use the equivalent of *= 1.5 (really *3/2), but I've had it fail when it got too big, meaning that I have to write extra code that falls back and tries additive in that case, and that makes it more complicated to present.

Comment: @SteveSummit What exactly would be the consequence of using a do{} while(c=getchar()...) here?

Comment: @Amir: do/while is useful when you want to make one extra trip through the loop for some reason.  Here, if there are 0 characters in the input, you want 0 trips through the loop, so I doubt that do/while would buy you much.  There is the problem of allocating enough space for the `'\0'` at the end, and you might be able to contrive a way to use do/while's extra trip to check that allocation, but I've never tried it.  Me, I sometimes write `while(true) {c=getc(); <<check allocation>>; if(c == EOF) {a[i]='\0'; break;} a[i++] = c;}`. This is a "break in the middle" loop.

Comment: Using `fread` or `read` (of `size - 1 - nch` bytes) instead of `getchar` can be faster.

Answer (score 5):

I would be remiss if I didn't add to the answers probably one of the most standard ways of reading an unknown number of lines of unknown length from a text file. In C you have two primary methods of character input. (1) **character-oriented** input (i.e. `getchar`, `getc`, etc..) and (2) **line-oriented** input (i.e. `fgets`, `getline`).

From that mix of functions, the POSIX function `getline` by default will allocate sufficient space to read a line of any length (up to the exhaustion of system memory). Further, when reading **lines** of input, **line-oriented** input is generally the proper choice.

To read an unknown number of lines, the general approach is to allocate an anticipated number of pointers (in an **array of pointers-to-char**) and then reallocate as necessary if you end up needing more. If you want to work with the complexities of stringing pointers-to-struct together in a linked-list, that's fine, but it is far simpler to handle an array of strings. (a linked-list is more appropriate when you have a struct with multiple members, rather than a single line)

The process is straight forward. (1) allocate memory for some initial number of pointers (`LMAX` below at `255`) and then as each line is read (2) allocate memory to hold the line and copy the line to the array (`strdup` is used below which both (a) allocates memory to hold the string, and (b) copies the string to the new memory block returning a pointer to its address)(You assign the pointer returned to your array of strings as `array[x]`)

As with any dynamic allocation of memory, **you** are responsible for keeping track of the memory allocated, preserving a pointer to the start of each allocated block of memory (so you can free it later), and then freeing the memory when it is no longer needed. (Use `valgrind` or some similar memory checker to confirm you have no memory errors and have freed all memory you have created)

Below is an example of the approach which simply reads any text file and prints its lines back to `stdout` before freeing the memory allocated to hold the file. Once you have read all lines (or while you are reading all lines), you can easily parse your **csv** input into individual values.

**Note:** below, when `LMAX` lines have been read, the `array` is reallocated to hold twice as many as before and the read continues. (You can set `LMAX` to `1` if you want to allocate a new pointer for each line, but that is a **very inefficient** way to handle memory allocation) Choosing some reasonable anticipated starting value, and then reallocating `2X` the current is a standard reallocation approach, but you are free to allocate additional blocks in any size you choose.

Look over the code and let me know if you have any questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LMAX 255

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s <filename>\n",
                 argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char **array = NULL;        /* array of pointers to char        */ 
    char *ln = NULL;            /* NULL forces getline to allocate  */
    size_t n = 0;               /* buf size, 0 use getline default  */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;           /* number of chars actually read    */
    size_t idx = 0;             /* array index for number of lines  */
    size_t it = 0;              /* general iterator variable        */
    size_t lmax = LMAX;         /* current array pointer allocation */
    FILE *fp = NULL;            /* file pointer                     */

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) { /* open file for reading    */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate LMAX pointers and set to NULL. Each of the 255 pointers will
       point to (hold the address of) the beginning of each string read from
       the file below. This will allow access to each string with array[x].
    */
    if (!(array = calloc (LMAX, sizeof *array))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory allocation failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    /* prototype - ssize_t getline (char **ln, size_t *n, FILE *fp)
       above we declared: char *ln and size_t n. Why don't they match? Simple,
       we will be passing the address of each to getline, so we simply precede
       the variable with the urinary '&' which forces an addition level of
       dereference making char* char** and size_t size_t *. Now the arguments
       match the prototype.
    */
    while ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, fp)) != -1)    /* read line    */
    {
        while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
            ln[--nchr] = 0;     /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */

        /* allocate & copy ln to array - this will create a block of memory
           to hold each character in ln and copy the characters in ln to that
           memory address. The address will then be stored in array[idx].
           (idx++ just increases idx by 1 so it is ready for the next address) 
           There is a lot going on in that simple: array[idx++] = strdup (ln);
        */
        array[idx++] = strdup (ln);

        if (idx == lmax) {      /* if lmax lines reached, realloc   */
            char **tmp = realloc (array, lmax * 2 * sizeof *array);
            if (!tmp)
                return -1;
            array = tmp;
            lmax *= 2;
        }
    }

    if (fp) fclose (fp);        /* close file */
    if (ln) free (ln);          /* free memory allocated to ln  */

    /* 
        process/use lines in array as needed
        (simple print all lines example below)
    */

    printf ("\nLines in file:\n\n");    /* print lines in file  */
    for (it = 0; it < idx; it++)    
        printf ("  array [%3zu]  %s\n", it, array[it]);
    printf ("\n");

    for (it = 0; it < idx; it++)        /* free array memory    */
        free (array[it]);
    free (array);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_rdfile dat/damages.txt

Lines in file:

  array [  0]  Personal injury damage awards are unliquidated
  array [  1]  and are not capable of certain measurement; thus, the
  array [  2]  jury has broad discretion in assessing the amount of
  array [  3]  damages in a personal injury case. Yet, at the same
  array [  4]  time, a factual sufficiency review insures that the
  array [  5]  evidence supports the jury's award; and, although
  array [  6]  difficult, the law requires appellate courts to conduct
  array [  7]  factual sufficiency reviews on damage awards in
  array [  8]  personal injury cases. Thus, while a jury has latitude in
  array [  9]  assessing intangible damages in personal injury cases,
  array [ 10]  a jury's damage award does not escape the scrutiny of
  array [ 11]  appellate review.
  array [ 12]
  array [ 13]  Because Texas law applies no physical manifestation
  array [ 14]  rule to restrict wrongful death recoveries, a
  array [ 15]  trial court in a death case is prudent when it chooses
  array [ 16]  to submit the issues of mental anguish and loss of
  array [ 17]  society and companionship. While there is a
  array [ 18]  presumption of mental anguish for the wrongful death
  array [ 19]  beneficiary, the Texas Supreme Court has not indicated
  array [ 20]  that reviewing courts should presume that the mental
  array [ 21]  anguish is sufficient to support a large award. Testimony
  array [ 22]  that proves the beneficiary suffered severe mental
  array [ 23]  anguish or severe grief should be a significant and
  array [ 24]  sometimes determining factor in a factual sufficiency
  array [ 25]  analysis of large non-pecuniary damage awards.
```

**Memory Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/getline_rdfile dat/damages.txt
==14321== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14321== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14321== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14321== Command: ./bin/getline_rdfile dat/damages.txt
==14321==

Lines in file:

  array [  0]  Personal injury damage awards are unliquidated
  <snip>
  ...
  array [ 25]  analysis of large non-pecuniary damage awards.

==14321==
==14321== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14321==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14321==   total heap usage: 29 allocs, 29 frees, 3,997 bytes allocated
==14321==
==14321== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14321==
==14321== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14321== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: I think I understand everything up until the point where you start allocating memory. I am not very proficient with pointers and I think it is confusing me, could you try break down the main part of your code a little more (after you have opened the file). Very comprehensive answer though.

Comment: Think of it this way. When you are dynamically allocating what you will access as a `2D` array, you first allocate the pointers to the `rows` of the array (which will be strings). So in essence you first allocate `array[rows][]` and the columns (what will be the individual chars remain empty) Then each time you read a line, you have to allocate space to hold the line. This allocation for the line is your column allocation (each char in the string represents one column) So you already have `array[rows][]` which will point to the beginning of each string with `array[idx++] = strdup (ln);`

Comment: And remember, a pointer is noting more than a variable that holds the address of something else as its value. So all the pointers we create with the first allocation of `array = calloc (LMAX, sizeof *array)` simply hold the address to the first character in each string (line) we read from the file and store somewhere. After we fill the array pointers with the address for the first character in each string, we can then access the string with `array[0 - numlines-1]`. If it help, you can think of each `array[x]` as a simple string. You could do `char *p = array[x]` and then use `p` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I am very inexperienced and I am getting hit with alot of code that I am unfamiliar with.. I am looking at the reference to 'getline' and I don't really understand the arguments being passed. I understand the process you are doing but the syntax is really losing me here.

Comment: That is a bit of a twist, but straight forward. The prototype is `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);` When passing `lineptr` (`ln` in my code) which is simply a string (`char *`), instead of passing just `lineptr`, you pass the address `&lineptr` (making it type `char **`) which allows `lineptr` to be reallocated in the function (it's starting address will change, so you can't just pass a copy). The same applies to `n`. You generally declare `size_t n = 0`, but you pass `&n` so the updated value will be available when `getline` returns. (good questions - you'll learn)

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   FILE* fpInputFile = NULL; 
   unsigned long ulSize = 0;  // Input File size
   unsigned long ulIteration = 0; 
   unsigned char* ucBuffer; // Buffer data

  if(argc != 2)
  {
   printf("Enter ihe file name \n");
   return -1;
  }
  fpInputFile = fopen(argv[1],"r"); // file open

  if(!fpInputFile){
    fprintf(stderr,"File opening failed");
  }
  fseek(fpInputFile,0,SEEK_END);
  ulSize = ftell(fpInputFile); //current file position
  fseek(fpInputFile,0,SEEK_SET);
  ucBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(ulSize); // memory allocation for ucBuffer var
  fread(ucBuffer,1,ulSize,fpInputFile); // Read file
  fclose(fpInputFile); // close the  file
 }
```

Use fseek and ftell to get offset of text file

Comment: Alternatively, use `fstat()` to get the size of the file in a single call, instead of needing three...

Comment: using fseek() or fstat() limits what you can read to plain disk based files.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code for reading a file of unknown size and take every character into a buffer (works perfectly for me). Please read the following references to get a good grip on file handling:

- [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/),
- [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/),
- [rewind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rewind/),
- [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/),
- [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) (out of the scope of this question).

Try something like this:

```
char* buffer;
size_t result;
long lSize;

pFile = fopen("CodeSV.txt","r");
if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

// obtain file size:
fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell (pFile);
rewind (pFile);
buffer = malloc(lSize);

// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error 2",stderr); exit (3);}

/* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */
fclose (pFile);
```

Comment: Are you sure about that `fopen` call?

Comment: As OP was using `printf("%s",output);` code likely needs `buffer` to be a string with a terminating null character.

Comment: @chux, _I am trying to read in a text file of unknown size into an array of characters_ The string part is only for output I guess.

Comment: Agree `'\0'` not needed per OP's quote.  Yet OP also said "a very inexperienced programmer", so anticipating OP's next step - whatever it is - adding the `'\0'` insures proper subsequent string usage.

Comment: The other issue with this technique is that if the "unknown file" is being read from a pipe or stream or something like that, you're never going to be able to stat it or seek it or learn how big it is in advance.

Comment: @SteveSummit, right you are, although the above answer was written as OP mentioned a text file _CodeSV.txt_ need to be read using `fopen()`.

Comment: I think this approach will return you the number of bytes in a file not the number of characters the file contains. i.e windows line endings get collated into a single \n with fread. Therefore this is over-allocating +1 byte per every new line

Answer (score 0):

If size of the file which you are reading is not much large then you can try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

    int main()
    {
        FILE *ptr_file;
        char output[10000];
        ptr_file =fopen("lol_temp.txt","r");
        if (!ptr_file)
           return 1;   
        int bytes_read = fread(output,1,10000,ptr_file);
        fclose(ptr_file);
        printf("%s",output);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah true! But but for small scale codes like this it is "okay" to do so.

Comment: Well, obviously, opinions may differ on the threshhold, but I don't consider a megabyte "small scale"...

Comment: Okay, You win. I scaled it down to 10kB!  
Actually, I did so because he was unaware about the file size.

Comment: Don't use `%s`. `output` might not contain null character. Or it might contain several ones. You could use `fwrite()` instead of `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is better done using dynamic linked list than an array. Here I have a simple linked list that stores every char you read from the file. Since you said "ultimately I want to read the file into a string, and manipulate the string and output that modified string as a new text file" I finally created a string of the file. I tested it so I guess it should work fine :)
You can separate the interface and implementation of the list to separate file or even use obj. file of the implementation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char Titem; //just to identify it
// Interface of list
typedef struct node *Tpointer;
typedef struct node {
    Titem item;
    Tpointer next;
} Tnode;
typedef Tpointer Tlist;

void initialize_list(Tlist *list);
void insert_to_list_end(Tlist *list, Titem data);
void cleanup_list(Tlist *list);

// Implementation of list (only obj file is need in your application)
void initialize_list(Tlist *list) {
    *list = NULL;
}
void insert_to_list_end(Tlist *list, Titem data) {
    Tpointer newnode, last = *list;
    newnode = (Tpointer)malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    newnode->item = data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (last == NULL){
        *list = newnode;
    }//first node
    else{
        while (1) {
            if (last->next == NULL) {
                last->next = newnode;
                break;
            }
            last = last->next;
        }
    }
}
void cleanup_list(Tlist *list) {
    Tpointer aux1, aux2;
    aux1 = *list;
    while (aux1 != NULL) {
        aux2 = aux1->next;
        free(aux1);
        printf("\nDeleted"); //for testing purposes
        aux1 = aux2;
    }
    initialize_list(list);
}

#define file_dir "CodeSV.txt"
int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_dir, "r");
    int counter = 1;
    Tlist list;
    if (fp) {
        initialize_list(&list);
        int c;
        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF){
            insert_to_list_end(&list, (char)c);
            counter++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else{ printf("file not found"); return 0; }

    //creating a string with what you read
    char stringFromFile[counter];
    Tlist currentNode = list;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= counter; i++) {
        stringFromFile[i] = currentNode->item;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
        if (currentNode == NULL) { break; }
    }
    printf("WHAT YOU JUST READ: %s", stringFromFile);

    /*here you can manipulate the string as you wish. But remember to free the linked list (call cleanup_list) when u're done*/
    cleanup_list(&list);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `char c;` should be `int c` so `EOF` is distinguishable from all the characters read.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I guess that can be fixed by casting it to int before comparison like this: while ((int)(c = getc(fp)) != EOF)

Comment: Casting to `(int)` will not provide `char c` with additional values to store the typical 256 characters and `EOF` uniquely.  Use `int c`.

Answer (score 0):

Should OP wants to do text processing and manipulate *lines*, instead of reading the entire file into 1 string, make a linked list of *lines*.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

#define LINE_MAXSIZE 65536
typedef struct line_T {
  struct line_T *next;
  char *data;
  size_t length;
} line_T;

line_T *ReadFile(FILE *istream) {
  line_T head;
  line_T *p = &head;
  char *buf = malloc(LINE_MAXSIZE);
  assert(buf);
  while (fgets(buf, LINE_MAXSIZE, istream)) {
    p->next = malloc(sizeof *(p->next));
    assert(p->next);
    p = p->next;
    p->next = NULL;
    p->length = strlen(buf);
    assert(p->length < LINE_MAXSIZE - 1);  // TBD: cope with long lines
    p->data = malloc(p->length + 1);
    assert(p->data);
    memcpy(p->data, buf, p->length + 1);
  }
  free(buf);
  return head.next;
}

unsigned long long CountConsumeData(line_T *p) {
  unsigned long long sum = 0;
  while (p) {
    sum += p->length;
    free(p->data);
    line_T *next = p->next;
    free(p);
    p = next;
  }
  return sum;
}

int main(void) {
  const char *fname = "CodeSV.txt";
  FILE *istream = fopen(fname, "r");
  line_T *p = ReadFile(istream);
  fclose(istream);
  printf("Length : %llu\n", CountConsumeData(p));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing an `#include <string.h>` somewhere. Perhaps omitted for instructional purposes?

Comment: @David C. Rankin  `#include <string.h>` added for completeness.

Comment: This code silently truncates lines longer than 65536 bytes.

Comment: @pts.  True, yet with a debug compile, `assert(p->length < LINE_MAXSIZE - 1);` will fire.  As   `TBD: cope with long lines` comment implies, code needs to determine how to handle lines exceeding a sane threshold be it 64K, 1M, 1G, etc.   Code that accepted any upper bound until `SIZE_MAX` kicks in is a potential hacker exploit as it allows external forces to overwhelm memory resources.  Defensive code vectors on huge line lengths.